# Order BY - switches by clicking text

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-order-by

Heey.. I'm trying to make a order BY option when clicking a text, but I just can't figure out how to do it.. I have looked at a lot of ways that could do , but nothing comes out..
I want it to go from DESC to ASC then back. There must be a simple way to do it , probably I just cant see it. Kinda new to this stuff.

This is how it looks like

```
$select = mysqli_query($this->sql, "SELECT `name`, `id`,`item1`,`item2`,`item3` FROM `account` ORDER BY `name` DESC;");
echo('<thead><tr>');
echo('name');
echo('id');
echo('item1');
echo('item2');
echo('item3');
echo('</tr></thead>');
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($select, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
echo('.$r['name'].');
echo('.$r['id'].');
echo('.$r['item1'].');
echo('.$r['item2'].');
echo('.$r['item3'].');
}
```

Comment: normally if you don't put DESC, it will order ASC.  So you can set a variable to add/not add it.  However, why hit the database when the data is on the browser and you can get js to sort it without hitting the server?

Comment: I didn't know that ! Will check mother google how that works ! Ty